# Can jmeter monitor custom information like the thread pool size of my server program

Tags: java, jmeter

i want to test the performance of my server side program which is using Thread Pool for incoming clients and I want to use JMeter to simulate concurrent users. Can i use JMeter to determine the internal characteristics of my Thread Pool, like pool size and acceptance latency on run time. That is, i want JMeter to display throughput,response time,Thread Pool size of my Thread Pool which is embedded inside my server program. Can JMeter display the pool size of my server program periodically after little intervals?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "can i monitor with jmeter the pool during load test" then It depends if your program exposes this information through jmx or http.
In this case You can use:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/
- or http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PageDataExtractor/

Comment: Is JMeter not a performance testing s/w? I want to test my server program's performance through JMeter. I want JMeter to display graphs of throughput,response time.But there is a performance characteristic of Thread Pool system called Pool size and i want JMeter to periodically display the thread pool size of my server program. Before using Jmeter i just wanted to know whether JMeter can do it or not.

Comment: I updated answer as I now understand differently your question through your comment

Comment: Thanks! My issue is resolved through your new updated answer but i want you to answer one more question please. your answer really means "Jmeter can display graphs of any performance metric if and only if i expose the information through jmx or http" is this correct or not?

Comment: or database, or any protocol you can call through java api by creating custom code. If answer is ok , you should accept it and upvote