# JMeter: Performance testing of two different Thread Pools and their comparison

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, threadpool, testbed

My question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215760/can-jmeter-monitor-custom-information-like-the-thread-pool-size-of-my-server-pro) as it is too old and there may be new JMeter Plugins.
I have two Java Classes **Server1** and **Server2**.
 ***Server1 class extends [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).*** 
***Server2 class extends [WaterMarkExecutor](https://github.com/kasun04/siddhi-esb/blob/master/modules/transports/src/main/java/org/siddhiesb/transport/passthru/workerpool/WaterMarkExecutor.java)*** 
User can connect to any of these Servers through Socket and submit Runnable Objects( that calculate some Random number).These Runnable objects are send back to the client as responses.
For each Runnable Object i am calculating its resonse time and the wait-time it did in the queue of thread pool.
Each Server is exposing me its Pool size and throughput after every second. I want to display and compare the performance statistics of these two servers in charts.
Instead of develping my own library for this, i want to use JMeter. 
**I want JMeter to**
1)connect to Server1 
2)send Runnable objects at specific rate
3)receive executed Runnable objects back from Server1 (as responses).
4)display the response time and wait(in queue) of each received Runnable object on Charts.
5) Display throughput and pool size of Server 1 on separate charts.
6)then i want to use the same experiment(workload etc) on Server 2 and want JMeter to compare the performance of two servers.
***Now my questins are***
(1) Is it easy to use JMeter for this scenario? or i should switch to some testbed(or any other tool)?
(2)suggest me some useful links of JMeter that can guide me to do this.

Comment: why does some one give -1?

Comment: plz comment! i need help on my question. What is wrong with my question? Why does it  voted -1 instead of helping n guiding me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your problem statement - it looks like you have got a server application with which clients can interact by sending java objects using serialization binary protocol. Jmeter is generally not used for such testing as it generally caters to other well known protocols like http, jms, ftp etc. There are readily available samplers for these. However if you want to use java serilization your best bet it to perhaps use java sampler to write own request sending/response recieving code or to use a commercial plugin ( available for trial) like [this](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-java-serialization-applications-with-jmeter/).

Other alternative is to perhaps write your own test application and use statistics from there to create visualizations.

Comment: I read some tutorial on Beanshell script that allowed jmeter to interact with a class. Then what is the use of Beanshell script ? i thought that it will enable me to do this?

Comment: Do you mean to say that JMeter perfrms testing on application layer. Since ThreadPoolExecutor works in middleware level ,thus JMeter cant test it w/o some plugin(as u suggested). ???

Comment: Yes - on a very high level you can think of JMeter as a browser ( with limited capability)  sending lots of http request and receiving responses

Comment: The link in the first line of my question above is talking about JMX plugin that can help me if my server expose information through JMX. Can I use JMX plugin in order to solve my issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215760/can-jmeter-monitor-custom-information-like-the-thread-pool-size-of-my-server-pro

Comment: Beanshell is just another scripting means to interact with JMeter provided classes or your own classes and pass data around within your test scrpts.

Comment: The link you have shared is talking about a concurrent program at server side which is what web applications too are. It does not say that you can invoke a remote program by passing around serialized objects over TCP. JMeter for most of the general use cases is used to HTTP based interaction.

Comment: The plugin by ubik does what you need by passing java objects. Internally it accepts an xml format of java structure which it serializes to java binary.

Comment: Thanks alot. Now i got it. I think this is the reason that threadpools are always tested on testbed environment by first embedding thread pools in some multithreaded application and then testing that multithreaded application. ??? Am i true